# How to call sub function in a class in python?

Tags: python, function, call

(I'm very new to both python and stackoverflow.)

```
def A():
    def B():
        print("I'm B")
    A.B = B

A()
A.B()
```

output:

```
"I'm B"
```

This works well. What I want is to put that in a class like this(doesn't work. I just tried..)

```
class Student:
    def A(self):
        def B():
            print("I'm B")
        self.A.B = B
```

I have no Idea how to make the class and how to call the sub function in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python functions are `first-class objects`. [What is first class function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392402/what-is-first-class-function-in-python)

So the first piece of code is perfectly valid. It just adds a property `B` to the function, which can later be called using `A.B()`.

But for the second piece of code, this is invalid, as `self.A` returns a reference to `A` method of class `Student`

```
<bound method Student.A of <__main__.Student object at 0x7f5335d80828>>
```

`self.A` does not have an attribute `B`, so it returns an error

```
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'B'
```

Now a quick fix would be to assign it to `self.B`

```
class Student:
    def A(self):
        def B():
            print("I'm B")
        self.B = B

a = Student()
a.A()
a.B()
```

Although the above code works, it is a very bad way, as you will have to always call `A` for every object instantiated before calling `B`.

Comment: According to my understanding, function can have property, and method can't have attribute.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reference *self* because the inner function *B* is defined there. It should be like this:

```
class Student:
    def A(self):
        def B():
            print("I'm B")
        B()
```

Answer (score -2):

I never use classes, but could you do it this way?

```
class A:                       
    def __call__(self):          //  so you can call it like a function
        def B():               
            print("i am B")     
        B()

call_A = A()                     //  make the class callable
call_A()                         //  call it
```