# How am I able to return value from Python function without passing in parameter?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests

1. Why am I able to call to and return variable (HTTP request) properties from this function without passing a parameter first?
2. How does the f in f"abc123" work?

```
import requests

def oauth(r):
    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"abc123"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2TweetLookupPython"
    return r

my_json = requests.request("GET", url, auth=oauth).json()
```

The call to the oauth function in auth=oauth is successful, without having to pass its parameter, r. With the requests module, is the single character 'r' an implicit reference to a requests object?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not **calling** the function `oauth`, but just **passing** the **object** `oauth` as parameter to the optional argument `auth` of `requests.request`.

The `requests.request` itself calls the `oauth` when appropriate passing the `r` parameter. Look at what the documentation says about the optional parameter `auth` from `requests.request`:

> Default Authentication tuple or object to attach to Request.

You only call a function when you use parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`auth` is taking in a function as a parameter value.

This is allowed in Python, as functions are [first-class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27392443/17769815). That function may be called somewhere in the `requests` package, but this is a detail that packages are meant to abstract away; all you need to know is that the `auth` parameter is given as a function that takes in one parameter.

The `f` refers to a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) -- but in this case, the `f` is redundant since there aren't any dynamically evaluated expressions to be placed inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

1.) The `requests.request` function takes a function as its `auth` argument and evaluates the first argument of the function with a *request*. So, you pass your `oauth` function to `requests.request` function and it automatically evaluates this function with the *request* as the argument you call *r*.

You can see this if you just print *r* inside `oauth` when you run the code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

def oauth(r):
    print(f'r is {r} of type {type(r)}')
    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"abc123"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2TweetLookupPython"
    return r

my_json = requests.request("GET", url, auth=oauth).json()
print(my_json)
```

Note that I'm just using a test url here.

2.) A letter before a string modifies the type of string. So f'string' makes this a "formattable" string. For example, suppose I wanted a function that takes a string variable with a person's name and outputs a hello message based on that string variable. I could do something like:

```
def helloMessage(name):
    return f'Hello {name}, welcome.'
```

If I called `helloMessage('Bob')` it would return 'Hello Bob, welcome.'