# Pairwise multiplication of elements between two lists

Tags: python, python-3.10

I am trying to calculate the product of every element from one list multiplied by every element from another list. from each list multiplied by each other.

For example, in `list1` I have 4, which needs to be multiplied by 3 in list2. Next, the 4 in `list1` needs to be multiplied by 1 in `list2`. The pattern continues until I receive the output: `[12,4,36,8,6,2,18,4,21,7,63,14]`. I haven't been able to achieve this -- here is the code I have so far:

```
def multiply_lists(list1,list2):
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        products.append(list1[i]*list2[i])
    return products

list1 = [4,2,7]
list2 = [3,1,9,2]
products = []
print ('list1 = ',list1,';','list2 = ', list2) 
prod_list = multiply_lists(list1,list2)
print ('prod_list = ',prod_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. What you really want is two for loops so you can compare each value in one list against all of the values in the second list. e.g.

```
def multiply_lists(list1, list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            products.append(list1[i] * list2[j])
    return products
```

You also don't need a `range` col, you can directly iterate over the items of each list:

```
def multiply_lists(list1, list2):
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            products.append(i * j)
    return products
```

And you could also do this as a comprehension:

```
def multiply_lists(list1, list2):
    return [i * j for i in list1 for j in list2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension like this

```
print([i * j for i in list1 for j in list2])
```

**Output:**

```
[12, 4, 36, 8, 6, 2, 18, 4, 21, 7, 63, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two concise approaches.

The first uses `itertools.product()` and a list comprehension:

```py
from itertools import product

[x * y for x, y in product(list1, list2)]
```

But, this problem is very well-suited for [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), which motivates the second approach. If you're unfamiliar with the function, it takes in two parameters:

- A function that takes in two parameters. In this case, we use `operator.mul`, a version of the multiplication operator that we can pass into a function. Note that functions can be passed into other functions in Python because functions are [first class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27392402/17769815).
- An iterable of iterables of size two. In this case, it's our output from `itertools.product()`.

For each element in our iterable, it unpacks the element and passes each element as a parameter into the function specified by the first parameter. This gives us:

```py
from itertools import product, starmap
import operator

list(starmap(operator.mul, product(list1, list2)))
```

Both of these output:

```py
[12, 4, 36, 8, 6, 2, 18, 4, 21, 7, 63, 14]
```

If you want to extend this approach to more than two iterables, you can do (as suggested by [flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280538/flakes)):

```py
from math import prod
list(map(prod, product(list1, list2, <specify more iterables>)))
```

Other answers have suggested using multiple `for` loops inside the comprehension. Note that [some consider this approach to be poor style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#274-decision); the use of `itertools.product()` avoids this issue entirely.

<sub>If you have any questions, feel free to comment -- I'm more than happy to clarify any confusion. I realize that these solutions may not be the most beginner-friendly. At the very least, I hope that these approaches may be useful for future readers.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested loops to multiply elements of 2 list or more list to multiply with each other.

Corrected Answer:

```
def multiply_lists(list1,list2):
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            products.append(i*j)
    return products

list1 = [4,2,7]
list2 = [3,1,9,2]
products = []
print ('list1 = ',list1,';','list2 = ', list2) 
prod_list = multiply_lists(list1,list2)
print ('prod_list = ',prod_list)
```