# how to integrate a composite function using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I have two functions defined as integrals where the lower and upper limits are (0-1) and (0-10), respectively. I found out the `scipy` library and was trying to use it for this purpose. Below I am showing my functions.

```
f(x) = (p*x) dx

g(x) = alpha*(ln(f(x))) dx
```

I am trying to calculate the value of function `g(x)`, but I could not find how to connect those two functions since they are composite functions.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

def firstMethod(x, p1):
    return p1 * x

def firstIntegral():
    return quad(firstMethod, 0, 1, args=(4))[0]

def secondMethod(x, alpha):
    return alpha*math.log(firstIntegral)

def secondIntegral():
    return quad(secondMethod, 0, 10, args=(0.5))[0]

print(secondIntegral())
```

I am receiving the error of

```
TypeError: must be real number, not function
```

Comment: Looks like an error here: `math.log(firstIntegral)`. You can't take the logarithm of a function. You have to evaluate the function and then take the logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `secondMethod`. Right now you're passing the function `firstIntegral` itself ([functions are first class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392402/what-is-first-class-function-in-python) in Python). You need to *call* the function, i.e. put parentheses after its name and pass in any arguments it needs.

For example, you could change your `secondMethod` to this:

```py
def secondMethod(x, alpha):
    return alpha * math.log(firstIntegral())  # Call the function.
```

It returns `3.4657359027997265`.