# Condition as a function parameter

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have to write a function `copy_lines_with_condition(source, destination, condition)` to copy lines that meet a certain condition from a source file to a destination file.

If I do not pass the condition as a parameter in the function:

```
def copy_lines_with_condition(source, destination): 
    with open(source) as in_file, open(destination, 'w') as out_file: 
        for line in in_file: 
            if len(line) >=10 and ' ' in line: # example of a condition to be met
                out_file.write(line)
```

But I am asked to pass the condition as a parameter, but I don't know how to refer to the condition when I want to execute the function.

```
def copy_lines_with_condition(source, destination, condition): 
    with open(source) as in_file, open(destination, 'w') as out_file: 
        for line in in_file: 
            if condition
                out_file.write(line)
```

Function testing:

```
source = 'source.txt'
destination = 'destination.txt'
condition = len(line) >=10 and ' ' in line
```

I understand that this is not working, `line` can not be reached outside the function. But I don't know how to properly solve the problem.

Comment: You want to look at this answer that shows how to use functions as first-class functions in python (passing functions around as variables/arguments and using them). https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448217/529630 . In addition to that, you want to create a function that takes the line as an argument and returns a boolean as to whether that line should be copied or not.

Comment: There's no beginner-friendly way to define an arbitrary set of "rules" and pass them into a function to be evaluated.  The closest thing would probably be a lambda function, but that's not quite a beginner-level topic.

Comment: In this specific case you could probably define a regular expression and pass it in to the function, and the function could check to see if each line matches the regex.  But a regex wouldn't be able to handle all the possible conditions you might want to use.

Comment: @JohnGordon I think higher order functions can be taught early enough, but I usually skip talking about lambdas in favor of normal functions. The `key` parameter to `min`, `max`, and `sorted` are all great ways to introduce new programmers to the concept.

Answer (score 2):

In python, functions are objects like most else. You can pass in a function as a parameter to your function. This is commonly called a higher-order-function!

So to rework this:

```
def copy_lines_with_condition(source, destination, condition): 
    with open(source) as in_file, open(destination, 'w') as out_file: 
        for line in in_file: 
            if condition(line):
                out_file.write(line)
```

```
def my_condition(line):
    return len(line) >=10 and ' ' in line

...
copy_lines_with_condition(source, destination, my_condition)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a predicate that can be called to evaluate the condition.

```
def copy_lines_with_condition(source, destination, predicate): 
    with open(source) as in_file, open(destination, 'w') as out_file: 
        for line in in_file: 
            if predicate(line):
                out_file.write(line)

copy_lines_with_condition('source.txt', 'destination.txt', lambda line: len(line >= 10 and ' ' in line)
```

---

Tangential, but to make testing easier, your function should take file-like objects, not file names, as arguments.

```
def copy_lines_with_condition(in_file, out_file, predicate): 
    for line in in_file: 
        if predicate(line):
            out_file.write(line)

with open('source.txt') as in_file, open('destination.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    copy_lines_with_condition(in_file, out_file, lambda line: len(line >= 10 and ' ' in line)
```