# Function defined with argument but called without it: how?

Tags: python, function, arguments

The code is:

```
def _proc_and_batch(self, ds, batch_size):
      def _process_data(x_):
        img_ = tf.cast(x_['image'], tf.int32)
        img_.set_shape(self._img_shape)
        return pack(image=img_, label=tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32))

      ds = ds.map(_process_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)    
      ds = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
      ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      return ds
```

How can **_process_data** be called without giving it an input? So, what's its input?

For reference, the code is taken from here:

https://github.com/hojonathanho/diffusion/blob/master/diffusion_tf/tpu_utils/datasets.py

Comment: You are not calling that function. You are passing it as a reference in map function. It is the map function which calls _process_data and supplies input to it. See example of how a map function operates.  https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp

Comment: So the map function is using it, right?

Comment: Yes. Map function invokes _process_data.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Any difference between First Class Function and High Order Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10141124/4720957)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called it yet. When you pass `_process_data` to `ds.map(...)` you're giving it the function and then it'll call the function itself with input latter. Try passing in `_process_data()` (with parentheses) to `map`, you'll get an error.